# Merge Module not found. Installshield 8

Tags: installshield

We're using Installshield 8 in creating our installer.

While building, we are getting this error.

```
Error -4075: File not found.
```

We traced the problem to a "missing" Merge Module. The weird thing is, the Merge Module does exist in the correct location! Browsing the merge module manually solved the problem. So we checked-in the *fixed* ISM file, restored the build machine (We had it snapshot'd), fetched the entire tree and built from there. Still, the merge module problem is there.

I noticed that when you browsed for the "missing" Merge Module, the problem will no longer exist even if you did not save the ISM file.

Have anyone experienced this problem?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Our Merge Module is not located in the Default Location for Merge Modules where Installshield is looking. In the newer version of IIS, there is a -O flag for IsCmdBld.exe which allows you to specify additional locations for your custom merge modules. One option that we have is to just copy our merge module to one of those Default Locations. But if someone can have a "neater" solution, please. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on `Tools/Options/Merge Modules` you can specify the directories in which you want the IDE to search for merge modules; in other words, expand the number of "default" locations where IS will search.*

For command-line building, you are correct; you have to use the "-o" switch.

*Disclaimer: this holds true for modern versions of InstallShield (last 5 years).  I assume IS8 is the same, but YMMV.

Comment: IS8 Developer edition (ISCMDBLD.EXE) does not have the -O option. However, the Standalone version (ISSABLD.EXE) does. Thanks!